# Sharing data between two as3 scripts?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm very new to actionscript. I've been editing some scripts for an old console emulator to get them to send score data. All of that is done, but now I need to share some data between two scripts. What's an easy way (for a beginner) to do this? Basically, there's a script where you can load a save state. If that function is called I need to disable sending score data to my server (since it would allow people to cheat). I need a variable or something that lets me know if a saved state has been loaded.

I thought one way might be through cookies. Can a flash web object set and get a cookie?

Comment: Can you define more clearly what you mean by "two scripts"? Are they two bits of code or two classes in the same application or do you have two applications?

Comment: The "cookie" of Flash Player is **[`SharedObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html)** which you can use to store and read data ...